# disable web proxy for a WCF client?

Tags: wcf, .net-4.0, proxy

My computer have a proxy server defined globally (in internet options configuration).

I have a .Net 4 application that use a WCF client to a remote host. The client code has been generated by VS add service reference dialog. As my proxy can't reach the host, each call ends with a communication exception.

How can I set up my client configuration to not use the default proxy ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can tell WCF not to use the default proxy by setting the [BasicHttpBinding.UseDefaultWebProxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.basichttpbinding.usedefaultwebproxy.aspx) to `false`:

```
<client>
    <endpoint address="http://server/myservice"
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              contract="IMyService" />
</client>
<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding useDefaultWebProxy="false" />
    </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: thanks, you've saved my life, I've been on it a week using system.net defaultProxy entries :)

Answer (score 2):

In your Binding configuration, set useDefaultWebProxy=false