# Big Performance Issue between WCF and Trend Micro (Security Suite)

Tags: performance, wcf, backend, network-protocols, antivirus

I am currently have a big perfomance issue with Trend Micro (Virus Security Software).

Our Client based on a Backend via `WCF` normaly needs `~ 6 sec` for startup without Trend Micro. With Trend Micro activated, it needs `~ 43 secs`.

This is an Performance decrease by `562 %`

Somebody else has had such a problem? What have you done to increase the performance? What is the reason for this poor performance?

**The perfomance break definity comes from each WCF Call.**

Here are Some profiles:

**Without Trend Micro**

[image: Without Trend Micro]

**With Trend Micro**

[image: With Trend Micro]

Comment: Saw this with windows application suite on Trend Micro box. Low powered server (Small business as well) and a ridiculous av scan schedule. Not Trend as such, just the PC had very few resources left to do anything useful.

Comment: Please try to narrow down what causes the startup delay (and explain what you mean by that). Is it the first request that is slow? Does Trend Micro install a proxy server to inspect all HTTP traffic? Then configure your application to circumvent that proxy as explained in [disable web proxy for a WCF client?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579756/disable-web-proxy-for-a-wcf-client).

Comment: Thanks for your comments. It is not only one time, it is on each WCF call from our ViewModel. Not sure how Trend Micro is working. The Delay is specific for each WCF call.

Comment: Your edit does not add information that wasn't present in your post before: it is clear it is slower when Trend Micro is active. You really need to narrow down the source of this issue. Check the proxy configuration in your browser when Trend Micro is activated, does it define a proxy? Did you try disabling the proxy like I suggested? Do other HTTP applications suffer from this slowness, especially on the same endpoint? Is the WCF endpoint an internal network or external address? Do you use a (self-signed) certificate on the endpoint?

Comment: @CodeCaster Yes i double checked it. No Changes with disabled proxy. It is an internal network endpoint. I have no other Http Appicliations installed. In a Browser i don't see it, but it is only one http call. In current dev State, the communication is via http and not https (No Certificate). I can definitive break it down to `Systen.Net.Socket.Receive` which is the `WCF Call`. Thanks.