# Disable WCF Data Service Client to use system proxy

Tags: c#, wcf, proxy, wcf-data-services, wcf-client

I am using wcf data service as client like this:

```
var context = new MyDerivedDataServiceContext(service_uri);
var res = context.Execute<bool>(service_uri, "GET", true).First();
```

but my application always uses default system proxy while executing.
How can I disable using system proxy?
(I am using OData version 5.6 on windows 8.1)

**Edit**:

I have checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579756/disable-web-proxy-for-a-wcf-client)  but this does not work for wcf data service.
I encountered such a problem when a user using Psiphon3 force shutdown or quit the proxy application, and the proxy IP/Port remains on system.

The problem is how my application does not use the system proxy and connect directly?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

By my understanding, You need to set your system proxy to bypass those addresses.

Control panel -> Internet options-> Connections-> LAN Settings -> Advanced

Then you can set the bypass address.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I want to this without changing the system proxy like this answer: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579756/disable-web-proxy-for-a-wcf-client?rq=1)