# C# consuming soap WS returns Security header error in VerifyIncomingMessage

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap

I have a SoapUI project that has a request with credentials in soap header like this

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:rgw="http://ThirdPartyWebService.wsdl">
 <soapenv:Header>
  <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasisopen.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasisopen.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-12346579123456789">
  <wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username>
  <wsse:Password>password</wsse:Password>
</wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
.........
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

SoapUI project works well and i get the response of this kind:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <env:Header/>
   <env:Body>
      <m:ThirdPartyWSMethodResponse xmlns:m="http://gr/gsis/ThirdPartyWS/ThirdPartyWS.wsdl">
         <ThirdPartyWSBasic_out>
            <m:string1>string 1</m:string1>
            <m:date1 xsi:nil="true"/>
            <m:string2>string 2</m:string2>
         </ThirdPartyWSBasic_out>
         <arrayOfThirdPartyWSFirmAct_out>
            <m:ThirdPartyWSFirmActUser>
               <m:Descr>some free text</m:Descr>
               <m:Kind>1</m:Kind>
               <m:KindDescr>some string</m:KindDescr>
               <m:Code>some code as string</m:Code>
            </m:ThirdPartyWSFirmActUser>
         </arrayOfThirdPartyWSFirmAct_out>
         <pCallSeqId_out>111111111</pCallSeqId_out>
         <pErrorRec_out>
            <m:errorDescr xsi:nil="true"/>
            <m:errorCode xsi:nil="true"/>
         </pErrorRec_out>
      </m:ThirdPartyWSMethodResponse>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

I'm trying to consume the same soap WS in a C# project with this code (I added it as a Service Reference):

```
    ThirdPartyWSClient client = new ThirdPartyWSClient();
    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password";

    System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (senderX, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

    ThirdPartyWSInputUser inputBody = new ThirdPartyWSInputUser();
    inputBody.parameter1 = "800542811";

    ThirdPartyWSBasicUser ThirdPartyWSBasic_out = new ThirdPartyWSBasicUser();
    ThirdPartyWSUserArray arrayOfThirdPartyWS_out = new ThirdPartyWSUserArray();
    decimal pCallSeqId_out = new decimal();
    GenWsErrorUser pErrorRec_out = new GenWsErrorUser();
    client.thirdPartyWSMethod(inputBody, ref ThirdPartyWSBasic_out, ref arrayOfThirdPartyWS_out, ref pCallSeqId_out, ref pErrorRec_out);
```

with bindings:

```
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="ThirdPartyWSPublic">
                    <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential" />
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="https://www.ThirdPartyWS/ThirdPartyWSPublicPort"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="RgWsPublic"
                contract="SoapWebService.ThirdPartyWSPublic" name="ThirdPartyWSPublicPort" />
        </client>
```

And I receive the following error:

> *Security processor was unable to find a security header in the message. This might be because the message is an unsecured fault or because there is a binding mismatch between the communicating parties.   This can occur if the service is configured for security and the client is not using security.*
>   With this stack trace:

```
Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.TransportSecurityProtocol.VerifyIncomingMessageCore(Message& message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.TransportSecurityProtocol.VerifyIncomingMessage(Message& message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityProtocol.VerifyIncomingMessage(Message& message, TimeSpan timeout, SecurityProtocolCorrelationState[] correlationStates)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.ProcessReply(Message reply, SecurityProtocolCorrelationState correlationState, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at .................................
```

The problem is that is cannot verify the incoming message. I used fiddler and found that **I get proper response from the WS**! The only thing that seemed strange is that my request included a timestamp element in the header and it did not have the wsse: and soapenv: expected tags but was like this:

```
<s:Envelope
    xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1"
            xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
                <u:Created>2020-06-05T13:35:58.208Z</u:Created>
                <u:Expires>2020-06-05T13:40:58.208Z</u:Expires>
            </u:Timestamp>
            <o:UsernameToken u:Id="uuid-11111111111111111111">
                <o:Username>username</o:Username>
                <o:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</o:Password>
            </o:UsernameToken>
        </o:Security>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <ThirdPartyWSPublicMethod>
        ...
        </ThirdPartyWSPublicMethod>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

The web service is a public sector WS and needs authentication thus I cannot provide it. Unfortunately I cannot show the exact requests and responses as they contain sensitive personal data.
I have tried everything I found here and there but couldn't solve this. Any help would be highly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: I think the timeout is the code is waiting for a proxy which you do not need.  Try disabling the proxy : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579756/disable-web-proxy-for-a-wcf-client?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem by using a custom binding and disabling timestamp and proxy. Thank you @jdweng for pointing to the correct direction

```
   <customBinding>
    <binding name="ThirdPartyWSPublic">
      <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" includeTimestamp="false">
        <secureConversationBootstrap />
      </security>
      <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
      <httpsTransport useDefaultWebProxy="false" requireClientCertificate="false" />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
```